# Installing Android SDK components fails in visual studio for mac

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to install some components of Android SDK in Visual Studio for mac but with some components I have problems during installation `Could not find a part of path`

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the solution but a workaround. Only the way I found to install correct SDK and emulators is to install `Android Studio` and  download and install sdk from it.

After I changed the location of SDK
[image]

For those who are not familiar with Android Studio, after installation and creating test project you can see in the top menu `AVD Manager`

[image]

After you open it you'll see a window to manage emulators

[image]

Hope this will be useful for somebody and I'll be happy ho hear real solution for this problem.